# Build and Publish MVC4 application using MSBuild in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, class-library

I have ASP.NET MVC 4 application who is referring 4 class project. Using Visual Studio when I publish solution it is publishing to folder with files

1.App_global.asax.complied

2.KII_Deploy.dll

But using msbuild in CI pipeline it is not producing those files.

Here I am using following .pubxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>\\KII_Publish</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>MergeAllOutputsToASingleAssembly</WDPMergeOption>
    <UseMerge>True</UseMerge>
    <SingleAssemblyName>KII_Deploy</SingleAssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I am using following parameters 
KII.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=SD.pubxml

I am newbie to msbuild and devops. I dont know proper way to build solution using MSBUILD. Also using above pubxml all dependencies are coping to publish folder but two files are getting created.I checked few questions on Stackoverflow which are stating issue with compression at CI server but that is not a case here.

Please help me, to know proper way to build multiple projects and get App_global.asax.complied and KII_Deploy.dll(Single dll of web project as output) using msbuild.

I have asp.net website also with no class library there same arguments are generating single dll as output.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build sln but it was not producing artifacts that I needed. Then I try to build using csproj of main project then I got artifacts similar to visual studio publish folder.